# jQuery function questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting some interesting results with my jQuery function. The code I am running looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      //Fade menu when play is pressed
    $('input').click(function(){
       $('menu').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

And it's used in my HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='three.min.js'></script>
        <script src='cannon.min.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery2.2.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='game.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery.js'></script>
        <title>really beta game lmaoo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                background-image:url('Images/backgroundImg.jpg');
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
            }
            input {
                position:absolute;
                bottom:21%;
                right:40%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <menu>
            <embed src='Audio/backgroundMusic.mp3' autoplay='true' loop='true' width='0' height='0'/>
            <input type='image' src='Images/start.jpg' width='275' height='150' onclick='INIT_GAME();'/>
        </menu>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script is producing an interesting black box effect, which is evident throughout the fade process. The reason for this is because the `<input>` tag is loading the scripts immediately from my JavaScript, which triggers the game I am making. I am trying to fade out the entire background and the button, and go straight to the game. It appears that the screen size changes as well, as scroll bars appear when the game is loaded. I don't want this effect either. My questions are:

- How do I fade out the background image in my CSS body style?
- How do I    call the `INIT_GAME()` function AFTER the fadeOut has
  been completed?
- Are the CSS styles I am using conflicting with the HTML elements I
  want to interact with due to the identical names?

You can view the effect here:
   https://scrigbildefense-browntj.c9users.io/main.html

Any help is welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the fadeOut, Aaron's answer of executing the completed function after fade:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      //Fade menu when play is pressed
    $('input').click(function(){
       $('menu').fadeOut(1000, function(d){ //function is called after animation completes.

           INIT_GAME();
       });
    });
});
```

You may also want to check out the options, see http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

as for your background image fading, You would be best to load an image inside the body, Then fade that image out using the same technique. ASAIK, you cannot fade a css background.

Your current code is not conflicting with any of your CSS names.

Just remember the rules of selector, this is the way I always think about it:

```
TEXT = element.type
#TEXT = element.id
.TEXT = element.class
```

None of the above is official, it's just the way I remember jquery selectors. This should also help you to make sure you avoid any conflicts.

Comment: Good method to remember it, this helped out a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){      //Fade menu when play is pressed
    $('input').click(function(){
       $('menu').fadeOut(1000, function(d){
           INIT_GAME();
       });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <menu>
        <embed src='Audio/backgroundMusic.mp3' autoplay='true' loop='true' width='0' height='0'/>
        <input type='image' src='Images/start.jpg' width='275' height='150'/>
    </menu>
```

Conflicting CSS can be an issue if you JavaScript is using CSS selectors to add functionality to the elements. It can also conflict with other CSS that is trying to style a different element with the same ID or Class. Usually, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this.

First, lets use event delegation in case this is dynamic content or we add any in the future, plus it allows us to drill down to the element you are really trying to influence which is the input.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    //we start by targeting the click on the parent element of input    
     $('menu').on('click', 'input', function(){
        //then run init_game as a callback of fadeout
         $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
               init_game();
         });
      });
  });

 function init_game(){
    console.log('the game is going!!');
  }

//init_game can be removed from your html
```